# How to create a type guard which doesn't lose generic type params

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic class `Schedule<T, D>` which contains a static type guard `isSchedule()`. The first version of the type guard looked like:

```js
static isSchedule(object: unknown): object is Schedule<any, any>;
```

While this works, it isn't ideal because if you pass a union type which contains, for example, a `Schedule<string, number>` type, the `string` and `number` type parameters are lost when the type guard narrows the type to `Schedule<any, any>`.

Example:

```js
declare const value: string | number | Schedule<string, number>;

if (Schedule.isSchedule(value)) {
  // value: Schedule<any, any>

  // ideally value would be narrowed to Schedule<string, number> in this case
}
```

Is there a way to construct the type guard such that any type parameters, if present, are not discarded when the type guard narrows a union type?

I've tried the following, which causes the typescript compiler to throw an error (but which seems to work, if you ignore the error--obviously I'd like to find a solution which doesn't throw an error):

```js
type Include<T, U> = Exclude<T, Exclude<T, U>>;

type GetScheduleType<T> = Include<T, Schedule<any, any>> extends never
  ? Schedule<any, any>
  : Include<T, Schedule<any, any>>;

static isSchedule<T>(object: T): object is GetScheduleType<T>;
```

#### Update

Two screenshots showing problem:

1. [image: Screenshot] using `fn(object: unknown): object is Schedule<any, any>` which does not work as intended.
2. [image: Screenshot] using hacky work around which does seem to work as intended, but which throws a typescript error.

Comment: Are you actually having this issue ? Could you share your full code ? My tests show that `object is Schedule<any, any>;` will preserver type arguments:https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwMpgBYmAVwhAB4BBAGngCEA+eAbwCh5n4oAueEgbiZYCMOlHi3jIALlDEBLMPCnJMOfIQAUAez4ArcGI54AdgGt9agO76AlBw3awYuWkW4CxKPoCeFN++o8AvgwMoEhwiGr64vAAblAQeCAc4jBS+gDm8AA+8Pp4ALZ8IDCZGNjOhERJKakUOfmFvoFSAGbwKk7KIAB08u0uKjFxIBYW9LzMA-GdUJ18UqnCLBNdfJ1iagCiAB4ADuEg+tKx-kA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir interesting, thanks. I am actually experiencing this problem--I've updated the question to include two screenshots--but I cannot seem to create a simple reproduction using `stackblitz` or `typescript-play`. Maybe I'm running into a problem elsewhere in my code or some kind of bug. This question came from an open source project, so you can [see the real code here](https://gitlab.com/john.carroll.p/rschedule/blob/4be52bb3d82c7f92acf21b315fd04ccbd542c512/packages/rschedule/src/lib/schedule/schedule.ts#L18-32). But I think there are too many pieces to include in S.O.